# Using aws s3 sync to synchronise files explicitly included and ignore everything else

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to use `aws` to backup my (Linux) home directory, excluding all files, except those explicitly included. So, I'm using:

```
aws s3 sync /home/me/ s3://bucket/ --region us-east-1 \
   --exclude "*" \
   --include "a/*" \
   --include "b/*"
```

Intuitively, this should backup directories `/home/me/a/` and `/home/me/b`, and ignore all other directories, e.g., `/home/me/.Trash`, yet I get the following error message:

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/me/.Trash/files/f.2'
Completed 1 part(s) with ... file(s) remaining
```

What have I gotten wrong?

Comment: You can add the `--dryrun` to check?

Answer (score 0):

It seems I was running an old version of `aws`, I upgraded following [Amazon's instructions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-bundle.html) and I no longer receive that error.